# Get the height of a div in afterRender()

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have an afterRender function that has an event listener for when the user scrolls down the page, it adds the fixed class to an element. Fixing the element to the page creates a gap that makes all subsequent elements look like they "jump" up. My idea was to create an empty div that will have the height of the fixed div and take its place when the scroll event happens, so as to remove the "jump".

My problem is that when I inspect the chpCard component in console (see the 'chpTarget' var) at event execution time, the element seems to be rendering without width/height. I've inspected it's offsetHeight and it reders to 0. But when I inspect it again once Lightning is done with it, I get the offsetHeight with the correct value. So my question is: How am I supposed to get the height? Isn't afterRender mean that everything is ready in the DOM to be used? Why is it rendering as a 0 height element?

This is the CMP:

```
<lightning:card class="slds-page-header slds-page-header_object-home" aura:id="chpCard">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</lightning:card>
```

And this is the render method

```
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
        var chpTarget = component.find('chpCard');
        var wrapper = component.find('chpWrapper');

        if (event.srcElement.documentElement.scrollTop > 12) {
            $A.util.addClass(chpTarget, 'slds-is-fixed');
        } else {
            $A.util.removeClass(chpTarget, 'slds-is-fixed');
        }
    });
}
```

I'm hoping there is some sort of virtual DOM that lightning generates where the true value of these elements exists, but I'm not holding my breath. :S

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You need to get the concretecomponent and dig in through that to get the value.

```
component.getConcreteComponent().getElements()
```

will return the base div. There is also a getElement() method to get a specific element.